# Why is text being sharpened in some applications?

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon

In some applications, dark (but not black) text on a lighter (but not white) background appears to have sharpening artifacts around its edges. [Here's an example that triggers it](https://jsfiddle.net/MrDOS/L3btrm9q), and here's what it looks like for me...

| ...in Firefox (normal) | ...in Chrome (sharpened) | ...in Word 2021 (sharpened) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: A screenshot of some dark blue text on a light blue background rendered by Firefox. The text says “I'm some dark (but not black) text with a lighter (but not white) background.”] | [image: The same content as in the previous screenshot, but rendered by Chrome. The text now has obnoxious white haloing as if a sharpening filter had been applied.] | [image: The same content as in the previous screenshots, but rendered by Word 2021. The text once again has a haloing effect.] |

In case what I'm trying to point out isn't clear (heh), the artifacting is more obvious when scaled up:

| ...in Firefox (normal) | ...in Chrome (sharpened) | ...in Word 2021 (sharpened) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: The previous Firefox screenshot cropped to the word “text” and scaled up 8×.] | [image: The previous Chrome screenshot cropped to the word “text” and scaled up 8×. The artifacts are more obvious.] | [image] |

I am *not* talking about the coloured fringes from subpixel text rendering. That is expected, and totally fine! I'm talking about the whitish haloing around the darkest pixels in the second and third images.

Here's a little more information about my environment, and what I know about the issue:

- I'm running Windows 10 21H2 (build 19044.2364). I have three monitors driven by a Radeon RX 480 (drivers version 22.20.29.10-221130a-386458C-AMD-Software-Adrenalin-Edition): two Pixio PX247 connected via DisplayPort, and one Pixio PX248 connected via HDMI. All three run at 1920×1080@144Hz. All three are set to 100% display scaling. AMD Software tells me that all three monitors have FreeSync enabled, “Virtual Super Resolution” disabled, GPU scaling enabled with the scaling mode set to “Preserve aspect ratio” and integer scaling enabled, colour depth set to 8 bpc, and pixel format set to “RGB 4:4:4 Pixel Format PC Standard (Full Range)”.
- This is not monitor-specific. The problem manifests on all three monitors.
- This is not a monitor misconfiguration! The colour settings on one of my three monitors do seem to exaggerate the effect, but I can clearly capture it in a screenshot, so some applications are definitely doing *something* differently.
- I first noticed this issue several months ago. (Text was definitely *not* like this when the machine was new). Changes around that time are murky: I did a rash of updates all at once, including a major Windows update (possibly 21H1), and a video card driver update. I didn't notice this issue right away, because I don't use any of the affected applications much. The uncertainty of what was updated along with the length of the interval since those updates were applied means rolling them back is pretty much off the table.
- I notice this mostly in Chromium-based applications (Chrome, of course, but also Electron applications, such as Slack), but as demonstrated above, other applications are also impacted. This makes me think it isn't an issue with Chrome as much as with whatever rendering layer Chrome uses. I think I've noticed this in some games, too, but any examples escape me at the minute.
- Triggering the behaviour does seem to vary a bit by application.

  - The effect is always visible in Chrome and Word (given appropriate content colouring, of course).
  - However, in Slack, the effect only appears when the window is maximized to occupy the very full extent of the screen – if it is on the same monitor as my taskbar (even the few pixels of the taskbar that remain visible when it is auto-hidden), the effect does not occur. (I have confirmed that this problem is not monitor-specific by moving the taskbar to another monitor, and observing that the now-fully-maximized Slack window now demonstrates the effect.)

This is driving me bonkers! Any clever ideas?

Comment: Wish you luck on this. One thing, though, the rainbow fringing is **not** to be expected. This is what your link generates on a Mac running Safari [screenshot then zoomed in Photoshop & screenshot again]. The workflow is fully colour-managed. No fringing at all - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBVkY.png There is a very slight rotation of hue, 210 - 214, but well within bounds

Comment: Thanks for the well-wishes. I've certainly struggled to get anywhere with it by myself. The colour fringing – a product of “subpixel rendering”; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering – is the norm for text rendering on Windows machines. You won't see it on macOS, because subpixel rendering has been removed from macOS as of Mojave (on the basis that retina displays don't really need it).

Comment: Ah, OK - it's still a horrible effect ;)) I'm on Mojave with no retina screens, 'regular' 2k 27". I did just realise why you get the hue rotation though - because the background colour is 201 whilst the text is 214, so any alpha/blend areas will vary between the two.